# Using "-var" with Terragrunt

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have two repositories "Dev" and "Prod" where I have:

main.tf

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "notification_channel_topic" {
  project = var.project_id
  name    = "${var.client_name}-topic"
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "project_id" {
  description = "ID of the project"
  type        = string
}

variable "client_name" {
  description = "Name of the client"
  type        = string
}
```

terragrunt.hcl

```
include "variables" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders("variables.hcl")
  expose = true
}

terraform {
  source = "../../../../modules/module"
}

inputs = {
  client_name = include.variables.locals.client_name
  project_id  = var.project_id
}
```

I need to pass project_id as argument, as it depends if it is used as dev and prod. As I need to have "Dev" and "Prod" repos same I can't have it defined in variables.hcl. When I run terragrunt `plan -var "project_id=dev_project"`
Error occurs
`Unknown variable; There is no variable named "var".` 
According to documentation it is possible to use -var with Terragrunt

"Any -var/-var-file options on the command line, in the order they are provided."

Am I doing something wrong or it's not possible to pass args this way?

Comment: Maybe an equals sign after `-var`, i.e., `-var="project_id=dev_project"`?